# How can I route ElasticSearch requests to a few shards

Tags: elasticsearch

My ES cluster has 12 servers, but when I create my index I just indicated 3 shards. So should I use the parameter **route** for each time writing and reading for making the latency shorted.

Comment: You want to store shards on same machine or what?

Comment: Your description of the issue is not clear. 12 nodes and 3 shards for that single index? 3 primary shards and 0 replicas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to controll shard allocation there is [few options](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-allocation.html)
One of the options you can set in config yml file **node.rack: rack1**

Then when you create/update index

```
PUT test/_settings
{
  "index.routing.allocation.include.rack": "rack1"
}
```

In addition it depends on size of you index, for instance in my app i am using different type of indexes and some of them have 1 shard (they are settings indexes) other have 3 shards and 1 replica, and i dont care about allocation because its super fast, so if you care about latency then maybe its better to think about upgrading network